# Is there anything like a small version of TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, testing, tfs, version-control

Is there anything that has features of TFS(Like Source Control, Debug, Testing,...) that we can use in a workgroup with a small team(say 1-6 persons)?

BTW: we are using VS 2008 Team Suit

Answer (score 5):

Do you particularly need it all in one package? Various open source projects only do one thing, but integrate nicely with others. For instance:

- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org) for source control
- [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) for bug tracking
- [Cruise Control .NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET) for continuous builds
- [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) for build management

Comment: Using all of them in a single package is much easier.

Comment: Open source does not mean free. Its usually harder to configure and setup, integrates poorly, and time-consuming to maintain. TFS is free for 5 users and also is Visual Studio Online.

Comment: @MrHinsh: I don't think it was in 2008. And I wouldn't assume it's easier to install and configure commercial software, either. Hopefully it's better now, but last time I installed TFS it was a horrible experience.

Comment: @MrHinsh: You don't have to install with GitHub, BitBucket etc either, do you? (And heck, there's a Git client in Visual Studio...)

Comment:   and there is Git in VSO, so why limit myself to mear GitHub or Bitbucket? http://nakedalm.com/why-should-i-use-visual-studio-alm-whether-tfs-or-vso/

Comment: @MrHinsh: You seem to be shifting your argument. You were arguing against using open source options because they were hard to set up. With GitHub - and yes, VSO - that issue goes away. So why would I want to use TFS (as you were advocating) rather than one of the far-more-commonly used tools such as Git or Mercurial? My experiences with TFS  have been almost entirely negative - and talking to various people over the years, that doesn't sound uncommon.

Comment: TFS and Git are not an apples to apples comparison. TFS does way more than Git. Do you maybe mean TFVC vs Git? Because I create all my team projects with Git rather than TFVC. But I get enterprise grade Git 

Comment: @MrHinsh: I really don't see what you're trying to accomplish in this discussion, on a question over 6 years old which wouldn't even stay open on SO these days (and which I've now voted to close, with an eye to deleting). The question was asking for alternatives to TFS, which I provided options for. If you want to provide your own answer (which I doubt many people will read). What benefit do you think you're providing here?

Comment: Not trying to accomplish anything... I got a notification of a reply and am replying... If noone cares then don't reply 

Answer (score 2):

Use the Team foundation **workgroup** edition but be [warned](http://notgartner.wordpress.com/2006/03/28/dont-install-team-foundation-server-workgroup-edition/).  Under no circumstances think of source safe.

There are many other very good alternatives for all you seek.  To many to mention, so will leave particular recommendations to others.

Comment: Where can I find Workgroup edition? I googled for about 1 hours but didn't find anything.

Comment: Team Suite should come with Team Foundation Server Workgroup edition.  Check your DVDs or download from MSDN.  You'll need to install Team Explorer from the TFS DVD on each client workstation as well.  TFS workgroup edition is good for up to 5 developers.

Comment: Is there anything else that I should install to use it completely?

Answer (score 2):

SourceGear Fortress?  Encompassing SourceGear Vault, work item / bug tracking, and integration with CruiseControl for build.

Is there something in particular you dislike about TFS?
Is there a particulare feature you feel is missing?
If you are using Team Suite, why not use TFS (even workgroup edition)?

Comment: The problem with the TFS is that it requires a dedicated server with a lot of resources.

Comment: TFS can run on 2GB of RAM in a VM using SQL Express so I don't know where 'lots of resources' comes from. If you have issue anyway then use Visual Studio Online...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with OpenSource, use [CodePlex](http://codeplex.com). So, you'll get TFS with all features for free :)
If not, please check [TFS Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Team Foundation Server is FREE if you have an MSDN licence. Even if you don't it is only $500 for a retail licence that allows 5 users.

if you have paied for Team Suit (now Visual Studio Ultimate) then you loose one hell of a lot of features if you do not use TFS.

Comment: But the license isn't to develop for it?, I mean, you get access to TFS but as a developer for it (plugins), not like user...

Comment: Sure, however you already have that to have tfs. So its free to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: You get 5 users for free and every developer with ab MSDN has access as a user to TFS at no cost. There is NO cost to develop for TFS.

Comment: You get 5 users for the TFS Express edition, not from the MSDN edition. Read carefully the terms, we have several MSDN licences here and our licensing manager explained this to us, we had to purchase it.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat as you. I even asked a [question about it here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291145/is-the-subversion-stack-a-realistic-alternative-to-team-foundation-server). We had the budget for TFS, and even the hardware to put it on, but with our team only being 5 people, going through the work to get TFS up and running didn't seem worth it. There was also a high training cost for a TFS administrator to take care of it all. Don't get me wrong: I **love** TFS, but for this team it was like using the space shuttle to cross the street.

As my question says, I looked at the Subversion stack. I liked it a lot. But at the end of the day, my customer wanted something that was vendor-supported.

We went with [SourceGear Fortress](http://www.sourcegear.com). It has the familiarity of SourceSafe but with the heavy-duty SCM features found in SVN and TFS. It was also significantly cheaper than TFS. In the end, Fortress was the balance my team needed.

I set up Fortress to use CruiseControl.NET for integrated builds, moved our VSS repository with the import tool, and was up and running in about a day.

I will admit that I miss TFS and wish I had some of its features, like the very tight integration with Visual Studio (Fortress has VSS style integration; bug- and issue-tracking are web-based).

Comment: You should look at Visual Studio Online. Its TFS in the cloud and its free for 5 users. In addition anyone with an MSDN licence gets access included in their MSDN...