# Are there alternatives to Visual Studio Team System and Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs, version-control, alt.net

Visual Studio Team System and Team Foundation Server offers a lot of goodies like source control, unit testing and automatic building.

I'm wondering the following: What alternatives are there for .NET developers that has all of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following questions might also be useful in your research:

- [What do you use as a good alternative to Team System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857/what-do-you-use-as-a-good-alternative-to-team-system)
- [Is there anything like a small version of TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268018/is-there-anything-like-a-small-version-of-tfs)

Hope that helps.

Martin.

Answer (score 4):

We're using

- Subversion
- TortoiseSVN
- CruiseControl.Net (with NAnt)
- Confluence and Jira (http://www.atlassian.com/)
- Nunit
- Microsoft enterprise library

It would be interesting to know how this product suite compares to TS/TFS

Comment: well, it appears to me much cheaper ;-)

Comment: Not realy true since Visual Studio ALM (used to be Team System) is now included with ALL MSDN subscriptions. And not just the Client, the server is also included and a licence to run SQL Server as long as its only use is for TFS. So its FREE :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any one product that will provide the same feature set, but *some* alternatives are:

Source Control

- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)

Unit testing

- [MBUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/)
- [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php)

Automated builds

- [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)
- [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)

Also check out [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/), which has the aim of providing a common platform for multiple tools to plug into and use services from